# Allow resizing of HTML frames while adding frameBorder=0 attribute?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, frame, frameset

Before the comments start screaming "frames are evil", let me add a disclaimer: "I am just porting a legacy application and don't have the time to get rid of frames!" :-)

There's a frameset containing two frames. I don't like the default frame border rendered by the browser (especially on Chrome & Firefox). It's too thick and feels obtrusive! So I thought i'll hide the default frame border using `frameborder=0` attribute on the frame and add the desired style on the content inside the frames. The problem is: after adding `frameborder=0`, the frames are not resizable anymore on Chrome & Safari, whereas IE & Firefox can still resize them. This is my code:

```
        <frameset rows="80%,20%" >
            <frame id="frame1" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" />
            <frame id="frame2" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" />
        </frameset>
```

Is there anyway to override the default frame border rendering and still retain the resizability?

Answer (score 0):

Style your frames with normal css, I think that should work, but yeah frames are evil and nobody uses them >.>

Try adding this to your frameset page styles:

```
frame {
    border: 1px solid #464646;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't help either! I still couldn't get rid of the ugly frame border in Chrome & Safari. Moreover, I guess, adding styles to frames doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

I made a script that places a handle bar inside the document with which you can resize the frameset in FF and chrome. Not perfect but may help:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function makeFramesetVerticallyResizable(frameSetId) {
        var frameSet = document.getElementById(frameSetId);

        // insert a vertical box called resizeHandle into the righthand document:
        var frameDoc = frameSet.children[1].contentDocument;
        var resizeHandle = frameDoc.createElement("div");
        resizeHandle.style.backgroundColor = "#999999";// remove this line to hide the handle
        resizeHandle.style.position = "fixed";
        resizeHandle.style.width = "100%";
        resizeHandle.style.height = "6px";
        resizeHandle.style.top = "3px"; // put it a little away from the border so firefox can detect dragging to the left
        resizeHandle.style.left = "0px";
        resizeHandle.style.cursor = "n-resize";
        resizeHandle.style.zIndex = 99999;        
        frameDoc.body.insertBefore(resizeHandle, frameDoc.body.firstChild);

        // Drag functions:
        var dragStartScreenY = null;
        resizeHandle.draggable = true;
        resizeHandle.ondragstart = function(event) {
             dragStartScreenY = event.screenY;            
             event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'dummy');
             event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';             
        };
        resizeHandle.ondrag = function(event) {
            if(dragStartScreenY !== null && event.screenY != 0) { // we have a mouse position ?
                var offset = event.screenY - dragStartScreenY;
                var height = frameSet.firstElementChild.offsetHeight;
                var newHeight = height + offset;
                frameSet.rows = "" + newHeight + ",*";
                dragStartScreenY = event.screenY;
            }            
        }        
        resizeHandle.ondragend = resizeHandle.ondrag;// Firefox does not give us the current mouse position during dragging, so resize the frames at the end        
    }



</script>
</head>
    <frameset id="mainFrameSet" rows="80%,20%" border="0" onload="makeFramesetVerticallyResizable('mainFrameSet')">
        <frame src="frame_blanc.php" id="frame1" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" />
        <frame src="frame_blanc.php" id="frame2" scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" />
    </frameset>  
</html>
```